# Termination checking of a function fails in Agda

Tags: recursion, agda, termination, proof-assistant

I'm currently writing the following incomplete function for [this project](https://github.com/XiaohuWang0921/agda-hott/tree/sized-subsets):

```
  extend : ∀ o asc (s : CSet (suc k) o) → SC asc → SC (add s asc)
  extend 0 asc s rewrite l≡0 s Eq.refl =
    restrict (add (empty _) asc) asc (add-∈ asc (empty∈asc asc))
  extend 1 asc s = restrict (add s asc) asc (add-∈ asc (asc .hasAllPoints s))
  extend {k} (suc (suc o)) asc s with has asc (_ , s) in eq
  ... | true = restrict (add s asc) asc (add-∈ asc (pser T eq tt))
  ... | false = result
    module Extend where      
      extendAll : ∀ bsc (ss : Fin m → CSet (suc k) (suc o)) → SC bsc → SC (addAll ss bsc)
      extendAll {zero} _ _ sc = sc
      extendAll {suc _} bsc ss sc =
        let head-ss = ss zero
            tail-ss i = ss (suc i)
        in extendAll (add head-ss bsc) tail-ss (extend (suc o) bsc head-ss sc)

      faces : SC asc → SC (addAll (except s) asc)
      faces = extendAll asc (except s)

      cycl : SC asc → Cycle P o
      cycl sc .face i = faces sc .for (∈-addAll (except s) asc i)
      cycl sc .compatible i j =
        P.proj (punchIn i) (cycl sc .face j) ≈˘⟨ P.map-cong (embed-except (except s j) Eq.refl _) _ ⟩
        P.proj (embed (except⊂s (except s j) i)) (cycl sc .face j) ≡⟨⟩
        P.proj (embed (except⊂s (except s j) i)) (faces sc .for (∈-addAll (except s) asc j)) ≈˘⟨ faces sc .compat (∈-addAll (except s) asc _) _ ⟩
        faces sc .for (Has-⊆ (addAll (except s) asc) (except⊂s (except s j) i) (∈-addAll (except s) asc j)) ≡˘⟨ for-resp (faces sc) _ _ ⟩
        faces sc .for (resp (_∈ addAll (except s) asc) (except-except s Eq.refl j i) (Has-⊆ (addAll (except s) asc) (except⊂s (except s j) i) (∈-addAll (except s) asc j))) ≡⟨ faces sc .for =$= T-irrel ⟩
        faces sc .for (Has-⊆ (addAll (except s) asc) (except⊂s (except s (punchIn j i)) (pinch i j)) (∈-addAll (except s) asc (punchIn j i))) ≈⟨ faces sc .compat _ _ ⟩
        P.proj (embed (except⊂s (except s (punchIn j i)) (pinch i j))) (faces sc  .for (∈-addAll (except s) asc (punchIn j i))) ≡⟨⟩
        P.proj (embed (except⊂s (except s (punchIn j i)) (pinch i j))) (cycl sc .face (punchIn j i)) ≈⟨ P.map-cong (embed-except (except s (punchIn j i)) Eq.refl _) _ ⟩
        P.proj (punchIn (pinch i j)) (cycl sc .face (punchIn j i)) ∎
        where open Relation.Reasoning (P._≃_)
              open Equiv (refl (P.Space _)) (trig (P.Space _))

      result : SC asc → SC (add s asc)
      result sc .for {s = t} t∈added with add-⊂ {s = t} {s} {asc} t∈added
      ... | inj₂ t∈asc = sc .for t∈asc
      ... | inj₁ t⊂s with ⊂-except t⊂s Eq.refl
      ... | inj₂ (i , t⊂except) = faces sc .for (Has-⊆ (addAll (except s) asc) t⊂except (∈-addAll (except s) asc i))
      ... | inj₁ (Eq.refl , Eq.refl) = ?
      result sc .compat = ?
```

As we can see, the only recursive call of `extend` to itself is in the final branch, where the first explicit argument `o` (which is a natural number) is pattern matched against `suc (suc o)`, and the recursive call itself passes `suc o` as the first explicit argument, so it is strictly smaller than the one pattern matched against.

Yet, Agda 2.6.4.1 rejects this definition and complains about failed termination checking. Am I missing something here or is this possibly a bug?

Btw, sorry for not including all the definitions used in this function, as there are simply too many. If you want to experiment with it yourself, a slightly modified version of this function can be found in the aforementioned project under [here](https://github.com/XiaohuWang0921/agda-hott/blob/sized-subsets/Universe/Presheaf/SC.agda), where the decreasing argument (named `l` there instead of `o`) is implicit instead of explicit (as originally intended), and `extendAll` is moved outside of `extend`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether this will help, and in any case your code fragment is much too complicated for me to think about digging into the details... but what happens if you change the pattern `suc (suc o)`, with subsequent use of `suc o` below, instead to `suc o@(suc _)`, and all subsequent occurrences of `suc o` now simply to `o` itself?

As far as I can tell, you make no use of the additional sub-term `o` of `suc (suc o)` in any call, so use of the `@`-pattern would both be more precise, and simplify the subsequent code. One might hope...

... but having said that, the termination checker is notoriously sensitive to recursive calls in the scope of an intermediate `with`, and that may be the *real* reason for your troubles. Is such behaviour a 'bug'? Surely not, except that we might hope for better. The 'usual' solution here is to write the auxiliary function by hand, mutually with the main one, but in your case, that looks... challenging!

Mind you, the `with` concerned is doing case analysis on a *boolean*... which for me at least, falls under the code smell of 'redundant uses of `with`', so I would consider refactoring to avoid that... which again in your case, would also involve refactoring away the use of the equation `eq`, but equations of the form `b ≡ true` etc. aren't really working hard enough to earn their place to begin with, are they?

Comment: I rewrote the code without using `with`, but termination checker still complains. Turns out, it's because the recursive call is inside a `where`-clause. I ended up moving everything in the `where`-clause into a separate module that takes an extra argument for the recursive call, and the complaint went away. Maybe it's my frustration talking but I think this is really too restrictive, because isn't a `where`-clause already just a separate module with extra arguments anyway?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have solved my problem and I think I'd shared the things I've tried in case it helps others:

1. I replaced the pattern `suc (suc o)` with `suc o@(suc _)` and every occurrence of `suc o` with `o` as James McKinna suggested. Didn't work.
2. I removed the unnecessary `with`-abstractions as James McKinna pointed out. It made my code cleaner but still didn't solve the problem.
3. I moved everything in the named `where`-block into a separate module (also called `Extend`), mutually recursive with the `extend` function. So now instead of having just one recursive definition that calls itself in the `where`-clause, I had 4 mutually dependent definitions. Didn't work.
4. I added an additional parameter to the now separate module `Extend` that receives the recursive call to `extend`, such that the `extend` function, having neither `with`-abstractions nor `where`-blocks at this point, would pass a recursive call to itself to the `Extend` module directly in the RHS. This finally worked.

So, I guess the conclusion is perhaps that Agda's termination checker can't deal with four mutually recursive definitions?